# Self updating application install with WIX?

Tags: .net, installation, wix, bootstrapping

I am writing an application that needs to be installed on a large number of desktops and also needs to update itself.  We are looking at WIX for creating the installation.  I have used ClickOnce and it is not a good solution for this install.  WIX seems to fit, but there is no good process for auto update that I have found.

I have looked at [ClickThrough](http://wix.sourceforge.net/ctvision.html), but it doesn't seem ready for prime time yet.  Does anyone have another good solution to use with WIX (or maybe another install program) to auto update an application install?

Comment: Hay, what tool did you eventually used for this? can you refer me to some guides?

Comment: I used WIX, but that is so long ago.  Sorry, I don't remember any of the guides, but not really in the windows world anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update Aug, 18, 2023:

ClickThrough is no longer a part of the WiX Toolset. The features of it were integrated into the update feed feature available in the Burn engine, but the remainder of this answer is no longer relevant in the WiX Toolset.

Original comment:

Yeah, ClickThrough really is what you're looking for here. There are bits and pieces in it that work. You might be able to dissect the code and use it yourself without all the extra "UI + build integration". Most of the bugs are in the higher levels. At the root, the RSS update and executable bootstrapper work fine.

Comment: okay, I will give it a try and see how it is...  I have just read that it still needed work to be ready.  If I can get the major pieces out of it then that might work.

Comment: Are there any walkthroughs, demos or documentation on any of this?  It seams "ClickThrough" implies a lot of other stuff that keeps getting pulled out, so I can't find anything about how to use the RSS and boostrapper at all.

Comment: This answer seems out-of-date at this point. According to the link below, ClickThrough is gone and isn't coming back in the same form. http://wixtoolset.org/issues/1412/ I don't know if there is an alternative or not...

Comment: @rbwhitaker Correct, this answer from 2009 was no longer relevant. I've updated it to note that.

Answer (score 7):

Just how "auto"-update does it have to be? :-)

We use WiX (2.0) for an app that needs to be installed over and over again. As long as you go with "major upgrades" from version to version, that works just fine - you can uninstall the old version and then re-install the new one - no major problems here.

The key is to have a stable "UpgradeCode" (a GUID in your WiX) that never changes - it's the key for your app - and to have a new ProductCode for every release.

Then, in your wxs file, you need two bits:

```
<Upgrade Id='--your-updatecode-GUID-here--'>
    <UpgradeVersion MigrateFeatures='yes' RemoveFeatures='ALL' />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallInitialize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

That should do it!

Other than that - nothing really much to say - it just works :-)

Comment: thanks for the response...  I am looking for something that can get and install the update over the network automatically.

Comment: With version 3.11 of WiX, you'll need to add two attributes to the UpgradeVersion tag.
`<UpgradeVersion MigrateFeatures="yes" RemoveFeatures="ALL" Minimum="0.0.0.0" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" />`

Answer (score 4):

Windows Installer isn't really designed for "self updating" software. If you don't need MSI,  or really need the application to "pull" it's own updates then use [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net/) or some other tool and write your own updating routine/service.

However if this is being installed on a large number of desktops within a single organisation, then the better solution would be to deploy an MSI via Active Directory. You can then "push" out updates using Group Policy. This is going to be much more robust than any application that updates itself.

Comment: Active directory is not really an option for me.  I will read up on NSIS and see if it will fit my needs.  Thanks for your answer.