# WIX - auto update

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I have a standalone setup project created with Wix. And I need some solution for auto-update my application. My application should check for a new version on startup and automatically download and install the new version if available.

What's the best solution to do this? Is there something like ClickOnce in Wix? ClickThrough seems to be dead, am I right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self updating application install with WIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798286/self-updating-application-install-with-wix)

Answer (score 4):

Update: re clickthrough... as I type this, v3.6 has been released, 3.7 being the next version which is slated to be out shortly, and ClickThrough isn't dead but now slated for release in WiX 4.0 ref: [See Robs comment 28th August.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/8/21/Enter-WiX-v3.7-toolset)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a thread about updating an application: [What is the best way to auto update a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395609/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application)

Basically, you need an updater application or custom code and a distribution mechanism for your updates.